# How to use id_rsa and id_rsa.pub on another machine for ssh to GCP VM from one other machine

Tags: ssh

I have two laptop, I created one `ssh-keygen` in first laptop and connected to GCP VM using ssh. I copied same `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` in second laptop and tried to ssh with same file permission but it is saying Load key

```
"id_rsa": Permission denied
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Is my approach is correct that id_rsa and id_rsa.pub should work as .pem file in aws.

I know how to ssh using gcloud command but i want to know why i am not able to ssh using same id_rsa.

Just give me some clue.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key in `id_rsa` is called the private key, and is not supposed to be copied to another computer.

The key in `id_rsa.pub` is the public key corresponding to the private key. This line can be appended to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the target computer. In addition, you must make sure that it is not writable by anybody except the owner.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to (and should not) copy the private key to to the server. The public key should be placed in `~.ssh/` with perms 0600 and `~/.ssh` itself should have perms 0700.